# How to process JSON plugin config with structs not known at compile-time

Tags: go, plugins

I am working with a Go-based software that allows to use several plugins.

- A plugin can't be used twice (by choice) => a plugin is either enabled or disabled
- Plugin names are unique
- All plugins are configured with a plugin-specific configuration defined as JSON-serializable struct

The use of plugins is controlled using a single configuration. Consider the following simplified example of the configuration struct:

```
type PluginConfig struct {
    PluginA *PluginA `json:"pluginA,omitEmpty"`
    PluginB *PluginB `json:"pluginB,omitEmpty"`
    PluginC *PluginC `json:"pluginC,omitEmpty"`
    PluginD *PluginD `json:"pluginD,omitEmpty"`
}
```

Somewhere in the code, each of the fields is checked, and the actual plugin added if configuration was provided:

```
if config.PluginA != nil {
    AddPlugin(plugina.New(config.PluginA))
}
if config.PluginB != nil {
    AddPlugin(pluginb.New(config.PluginB))
}
// ...
```

I am trying to rework the software so external plugins are supported as well. The software is required to still function as before, so the format and way of configuration cannot be changed. Additionally, I am required to use the default `encoding/json` package for unmarshaling the configuration.

If I knew all plugins at compile-time, I could `go generate` the *code* of the configuration struct before compiling, and generate the corresponding `if config.SomePlugin { }` statements as well. While this might even be of good performance because no dynamic lookup is used, I would be still limited to knowing all plugins in advance. If this was the case, would you agree this approach is a valid way to go?

What could I do if I could only get a list of plugins at runtime? How could I process the configuration file then, so not only the plugin names are dynamic, but I would also not know of the specific configuration before?

Comment: Use a map instead of a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Unmarshal to a generic type such as `map[string]interface{}`
2. Unmarshal to `json.RawMessage`

In either case, you can then pass that data to the plugin, once it's loaded, to do full unmarshaling/conversion.

Comment: thanks for your answer. `json.RawMessage` was new to me and looks good, but specific to `encoding/json`. How would the first approach work for me? Can you please look at https://play.golang.org/p/becZqXKP0zL where I've sketched my problem with it - namely converting it back to the *actual* type.

Comment: @muffel you can't do that, it's just not possible to type assert something as that which it is not. If you unmarshal into `map[string]interface{}` you'll have to convert that map to your *actual* type **manually**, setting each field individually using the corresponding map key-value pair.

Comment: @mkopriva's comment is exactly right. I don't think I can add anything.

Comment: If the plugins are dynamic, so are any types they introduce. That leaves you with no way to *write* the type name into a type-switch or type-assertion. You can find the type at runtime via reflection, but this mean that you must do the entire job at runtime (which you might as well do via reflection and access to the fields).